# Python s3 copy_from fails if "key" has spaces in it. How to search through file contents and then print file name stored in S3 using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to iterate through set of xml files stored in S3 and print file name based on file contents. The issue is file name has spaces in it so Python command:

```
S3.download_file(BUCKET_NAME, i['Key'], '/tmp/{}'.format(i['Key']) )
```

gives error.

Comment: What is the specific error you receive? Can you show us the value for `i['Key']` that is causing the error?

Comment: The error message is as follows: Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': expected an indented block (lambda_function.py, line 19)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
  "stackTrace": "File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\" Line 19\n\t        client.download_file(BUCKET_NAME, i['Key'], '/tmp/{}'.format(i['Key']) )\n"
}

Comment: The error message says "expected an indented block", which means the Python code was incorrectly formatted. It has nothing to do with the `download_file()` command.